# Max watt on LED dimmer

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, dimmer-switch

I have 16 9w (144w total) LED on one switch.  Is it ok to change that switch to a 150w max LED dimmer or should I go to a higher 300w LED dimmer?

Answer (score 2):

Go with the larger dimmer. It will allow you to add higher wattage bulbs down the road. Your 9 watt LED bulb is equivalent to a 60 watt standard bulb. That's a middle of the road wattage so allow for larger bulbs.

Comment: Will do.  Was leaning in that direction.  Thank you for the advice.